# Designer crashes in Visual Studio 2013 Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, visual-studio-2013

I have problem with my Visual Studio 2013.

When I open designer it throws error: `System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingException` and after reload, it appear againt and has transparent transparent like in picture bellow :

[image]

Of course xaml is full of buttons, but it disappeared in desinger...

The problem might be `AMD Catalyst Controler`, I tried reinstall it, but without results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install [Visual Studio 2013 Update 1](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=41650), the XAML designer had some stability issues fixed in this update and works alot better after I applied the update on my Windows 8.1 machines.

Comment: Yes, it started work some time ago after update.
It had do be a bug.